# fetch() Making Multiple API Requests in my React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, single-page-application, fetch-api

I am working on a React App and for making API requests I have used `fetch()`, but because of certain unknown reason `fetch()` is causing multiple API requests while I am expecting only one.

In the current scenario, I am getting 3 requests in the Network tab of my browser:

[image]

The code responsible for the same is:

```
componentDidMount() {
    var planet_id = this.props.match.params.id;
    let planetData = [];
    apiFetch('planets', false, planet_id).then(function(jsonResponse) {
        planetData = jsonResponse;
    }).then(data => this.setState({ 
        planet: planetData,
        loading: false
    }));
}
```

Definition for apiFetch():

```
export function apiFetch(fetchParam, fullUrl = false, id = false) {
let fetchItem;

let apiUrl;

if (fullUrl) {
    apiUrl = fetchParam;
} else {
    switch (fetchParam) {
        case 'people': {
            fetchItem = Constants.apiPeople;
            break;
        }
        case 'planets': {
            fetchItem = Constants.apiPlanets;
            break;
        }
        default: {
            fetchItem = Constants.apiPlanets;
        }
    }
    apiUrl = Constants.apiBaseUrl + fetchItem;
    apiUrl += id ? ('/' + id) : '';
    apiUrl += Constants.apiFormat;
}

return fetch(apiUrl, {
    method: Constants.fetchMethod,
    cache: Constants.apiNoCache
})
.then(response => response.json())
.catch(error => console.error('Error in API:', error));
}
```

The flow of the App is fine and it seems to work as expected, but I am not able to figure out what is causing multiple API requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem, the issue was appearing because of the missing trailing slash (/) at the end of the URL.

The API expects a / at the end. Updated code:

```
apiUrl = Constants.apiBaseUrl + fetchItem + '/';
apiUrl += id ? (id + '/') : '';
apiUrl += Constants.apiFormat;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first two requests visible in the developer console are showing a status code of `301 (Moved Permanently)`. It seems that your backend or web server is configured to redirect the requests you are making with the pattern `2?`.

If you send the right URL (which does not result in a redirect in the backend) from the `fetch` then you will start seeing a single request in the console.

Comment: But I am not sending any other URL for fetching, only a single API call is invoked from the code.

Comment: The issue is that whatever URL you are forming is resulting in a redirect response from the backend and fetch is following the redirects